# Find out if integration branch contains tip of local branches

Tags: git, git-branch

I want to get a list of branches I can safely delete. My question is, is there a way to determine if `remotes/origin/dev` contains a commit, without checking out that branch?

```
git fetch origin;
git branch | while read branch; do
  if [ "remotes/origin/dev" --contains "$b" ]; then
     echo "$b";
  fi
done
```

How to check if `remotes/origin/dev` contains the latest commit of a given branch? Can I avoid checking out `remotes/origin/dev` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor $b refs/remotes/origin/dev; then
    echo $b
fi
```

But don't use `git branch` for this!  Use `git for-each-ref` instead:

```
git fetch origin
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads | while read b; do
    git merge-base --is-ancestor $b refs/remotes/origin/dev && echo ${b#refs/heads/}
done
```

for instance.  (This uses full names for everything, just in case, but still emits shortened names.)

---

The question:

- *Does branch B contain commit C?*

(for some branch name / identifier *B*, including remote-tracking names, and commit hash or other identifier *C*) is actually a subset of another, more general question that is answered by the `git merge-base` command.

The more general question is:

- *Is commit C1 an ancestor of commit C2?*

where "ancestor of" allows for equality.  This is the test that `git merge-base --is-ancestor C1 C2` performs.  Note that any of these items may be hash IDs or reference names, and the result is part of the exit status (appropriately enough).  The `--is-ancestor` test was new in Git 1.8.0.